# How to stop site from stealing content with frames

Tags: apache, .htaccess, google-chrome, frame

I run a pretty large site and I have just discovered a hack Lithuanian site has 100% copied my site and all content via frames. I was able to prevent it in htaccess using

```
Header append X-FRAME-OPTIONS "SAMEORIGIN"
```

This got the job done in Firefox, Safari, and IE, but not Chrome. I've also blocked their site's IP address but that did nothing. Also contacted their host but nothing yet.

When I view source this is what it shows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Hi I Steal Other Site's Content</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<meta name="generator" content="ORT - Ovh Redirect Technology">
<meta name="url" content="https://example.com/page">
<meta name="robots" content="all">
</head>
<frameset rows="100%,0" frameborder=no border=0>
<frame name="ORT" src="https://example.com/page">
<frame name="NONE" src="" scrolling="no" noresize>
<noframes>
<body><a href="https://example.com/page">Click here</a><hr></body>
</noframes>
</frameset>
</html>
```

Any idea why it's not working in Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(document.referrer.indexOf("http://example.com/") != -1) {
        window.location = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0?autoplay=1";
    }
</script>
```